# Django,getting only unique values from related object

Tags: python, django

I wish I could render in my website list of most used tags,which I do.The problem is,displayed tags often repeat and I'm sure it would be much better if only unique tags were displayed.

In my model I have writen method `unique_tags`

```
class ArticleTag(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey('ep.Article', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tags')
    tag = models.ForeignKey('ep.Tag', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def unique_tags(self):
        return self.objects.values_list('tag').distinct()
```

and when I tested it in python shell it works fine.But it doesnt render any tag.My template looks like this:

```
            <div class="widget-tags">
          <ul>
            {% for prev_article in object.articles.all %}
            {% for article_tag in prev_article.article.tags.all.unique_tags %}
            <li><a href="#">{{article_tag.tag.verbose_name}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Where object is from model that makes relation with Article table and Field table,so with `object.articles.all` I've got all instances of articles that are related to specific field.I use detail view in my views.

So,my first question is,Is this valid approach? I mean,adding new method in model class, or perhaps I should add this in views?.Also I still not comfortable with django template language so maybe there is problem.And I know there is this filter in template like {{ some_object | function}} but I've read that it is good practice to keep as little logic in template as it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add logic for this on the `Article` level *if* you want to do this:

```
class Article(models.Model):

    def unique_tags(self):
        return Tag.objects.filter(articletag__article=self).distinct()
```

and then query this with:

```
{% for article_tag in prev_article.unique_tags %}
    <li><a href="#">{{article_tag.tag.verbose_name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

By using a `.values_list`, you will obtain the *value* of the primary key, so usually an `int` (or another primitive type given you defined a primary key yourself).

That being said, I think it is better to simply make sure that this can *never* happen, by adding a [**`unique_together`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) constraint in the model:

```
class ArticleTag(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        'ep.Article',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tags'
    )
    tag = models.ForeignKey('ep.Tag', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('article', 'tag')
```

So now you can simply not tag the same article with the same tag twice. So once this is enforced, you can simply use:

```
<!-- given unique_together is enforced -->

{% for article_tag in prev_article.tags.all %}
    <li><a href="#">{{article_tag.tag.verbose_name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

and you can then use `.prefetch_related(..)` to load all the related objects with a constant number of queries.